# Why is the Jacobian determinant continous in the proof of the Inverse function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why the first sentence in the proof is valid.

Comment: Could you please check in the original if it is, as one would expect, ${\bf f}=…\in C^1$?

Comment: Can you write the title of book and the name of author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to the answer of Oskar Linka, we can also see the continuity by looking at the Leibniz-formula for determinants.

First of all, note that $f \in C'$. (I guess $C'$ denotes the set of all maps whose partial derivatives exist in all variables and are continuous, i.e. all the maps $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ exist and are continuous.) Now, using the Leibniz-formula, we have
$$J_f(b)=\sum_{\pi \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\pi)\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_{\pi(i)}}(b)$$
for all $b \in S$. From this formula, we can directly read off the continuity of $J_f$ on $S$. It follows from the continuity of the maps $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$.

Now to the part about the open ball: if a map $h$ is continuous at some point $a$ and $h(a) \neq 0$, (e.g. $h=J_f$), there is always and open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ such that $h(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in B_{\varepsilon}(a)$. Proof: Assume that this is not true. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $x_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(a)$ such that $h(x_n)=0$. Now, the sequence $(x_n)$ tends to $a$ for $n \to \infty$. However, $h(x_n)=0$ for all $x_n$. Therefore $h(x_n) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. But this is a contradiction: since $h$ is continuous at $a$, we should have $h(x_n) \to h(a) \neq 0$ instead.

Note: $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ denotes the open $\varepsilon$-ball around $a$ where it is assumed that $\varepsilon >0$.

Comment: And the fact that $f^{-1}(Y)$ exists, is that because $f\in C'(S) \Rightarrow f\in D(S) \Rightarrow f\in C(S)$ and $f:S \rightarrow T$, $Y\subset T$ open, by definition of continuity $f^{-1}(Y)$ is open?

Comment: I think the $C'$ is a badly photocopied/scanned $C^1$, thus $f$ is continuously differentiable, as usual in the assumptions of the inverse and implicit function theorem.

Comment: @zermelovac: I do not know the reference you are using. But according to the author, the existence of $f^{-1}$ and of a suitable set $Y$ depends on "Theorem 13.4" and "Theorem 13.2". Since I do not know the book and the theorems in question, I am not really able to help you with this question. But the reason that $f^{-1}(Y)$ is open is indeed that $f$ is continuous and that $Y$ is open (cf. definition of continuity in terms of topological spaces).

Comment: @LutzL Rudin uses $\mathscr{C}'$ and $\mathscr{C}''$ for once resp. twice continuously differentiable functions in his _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_. Quite conceivable that other authors also do that.

Answer (score 2):

Determinant is continuous on operators over $R^n$ (it is a polynomial of the coefficients with respect to the canonical, say, basis) and the jacobian matrix is also continuous by assumption. Composition preserves continuity.